# Access Token becomes invaild after some time even offline_access is set

Tags: facebook

I can retrieve my App users information using access token just after the user accepted my App, and I have stored the access token into my database.
However, when I want to update the information later, the access token become invalid and Facebook returned "message": "Error validating application.". It's quite interesting that only some of my users have this problem.
I have **already set "offline_access" into the permission dialog**, so the token should not expire. Also, I'm sure that the users have neither changed password nor removed App.
So, will the token become invalid sometimes even with "offline_access" set?

Comment: Make sure that 'some of your users' doesn't remove the offline_access permission from their app!! Are you using the new oAuth dialog, this has options to remove each individual permission and then proceed with the application.

Comment: My app tester experienced this problem too, also I'm using the old Auth dialog

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found it was due to coding error.  The variable I used to hold the token was being garbage collected.  It didn't always happen at the same point in time so it was a bit confusing.

So, my suggestion is, make sure the variable holding the token is a class varible.